# OUTPUT clause in Entity Framework issues

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update some data in a partitioned view in SQL Server using Entity Framework.

I managed to map the view (`toTable`) and I can query select and insert but I can't do update. I think that the reason is that SQL UPDATE generated by Entity Framework contains `OUTPUT 1` clause but partitioned view does not support it - error thrown by SQL Server:

> The OUTPUT clause cannot be specified because the target view "MyView" is a partitioned view.

Is there any workaround for it?

I tried trick with triggers:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyView>()
        .ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("SomeTrigger"));
```

It works as then in generated update sql query there is no output 1 clause but it is not very erlegant, is there better way for it?

SQL generated by EF after changes:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [MyView] SET [TestColumn] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
...parameters values
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any workaround for it?

Instead of letting SQL Server figure out the inserts for the partitioned view, you might use an INSTEAD OF trigger instead.

> For INSTEAD OF triggers, the returned results are generated as if the
> INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE had actually occurred, even if no
> modifications take place as the result of the trigger operation.

[OUTPUT - TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#triggers)

Comment: What I did is that I configured it like that:   modelBuilder.Entity<MyView>().ToTable("MyView", tb => tb.HasTrigger("IsPartitionedView")); It works because then there is no OUTPUT 1 clause in generated update query but this is not very elegant. Is there any nicer way of accomplishing the same?

Comment: My suggestion is to add an INSTEAD OF trigger and remove the .HasTrigger() configuration.

Comment: But where should I add that trigger? To the table in database?

Comment: The INSTEAD OF trigger would be on the view.  Then you can perform the appropriate operations to the base tables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16#types-of-dml-triggers